# C#, No video, audio only, VLC using multiple forms, Black Screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, activex, vlc

Can someone please tell me whey I am getting a black screen with no video, only sound?

```
private void screen1btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScreenOne playScreen1 = new ScreenOne();
        playScreen1.PlayScreenOne();
    }
```

... and the other form is like this:

```
public partial class ScreenOne : Form
{
    public ScreenOne()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void PlayScreenOne()
    {
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("file:///" + @"Filepath", null);
        axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
    }




}
```

Sound works fine, but no video. All the properties of the VLC are left to default, is there something I need to change when using this plugin across multiple forms?   Anyone know what's wrong?

Update:: I rebuilt the program in WPF and I am having the same problem. When I have a button on the second form (same form as player) it works fine, as soon as I call it from the main form, sound only. ugh!

Comment: Please someone help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem on my own!

When I was creating this instance,

```
ScreenOne playScreen1 = new ScreenOne();
```

I was actually creating a redundant instance of what I was trying to do, I'm not sure if that's the right way to put it but I basically already had an instance of the second form and was making another separate instance of the form that was named differently.

I already had in my code to open the second form

```
Screen2 Screen2 = new Screen2(); 
private void openScreen2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Screen2.Show();
    }
```

Then later was doing this which is WRONG, I was adding playscreen1 when I should still have been using Screen2.

```
Screen2 playScreen1 = new Screen2();
playScreen1.PlayScreenOne();
```

So when I wanted to use the method to play the media player on the second form from the first one, I just needed to use the same instance of Screen2 that I had created to open the form to begin with instead of created a new instance for what method I wanted to use.

IDK if my explanation makes sense, or maybe its basics to most people (I'm a noob), but if anyone comes across this problem, message me and I'll try to help.

o7

Answer (score 0):

I dont know but i can give some solution suggestions,

1. Make sure the VLC program is installed as 32-bit. I dont know, I've solved a problem that way.
2. I think high probabilty your problem is based on about "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins"  Check your plugins. maybe your audio_filter, audio_mixer, audio_output plugins are missing.

you can remove Vlc, then download and install last VLC 32 bit.

I think that will solve your problem. Dont forget AxAXVLC works with vlc plugins.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that. The same problem occurs when I use windows media player as well.  All I am trying to do is be able to control multiple video screens from one form, but I'm lost. Thanks anyway tho.